# Combining queried items

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Trying to combine queried items, but sometimes an individual queries produces nil, an empty array, or both.

```
@items = relation_1 + relation_2 + relation_3
@items.shuffle!
```

I thought this would be the solution:

```
@items = [relation_1, relation_2, relation_3].compact.flatten
```

Compact removes nil, but flatten removes everything else instead of just the empty array. Any other solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
@itmes = [relation_1, relation_2, relation_3].flatten.select(&:present?)
```

[Documentation about `.present?`](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/present%3F)

Comment: The first line raises an exception because `nil` can't be combined with an array

Answer (score 2):

If this is a rails app you can do this:

```
@items = [relation_1, relation_2, relation_3].reject &:blank?
```